# jQuery Slider Step Attribute Not Working

Tags: jquery, user-interface, slider

Here is the code I am using to create my slider:

```
    $(".slider").slider({ 
    steps: 10, 
    animate: true,
    range: true, 
    min: 0, 
    max: 500, 
    values: [range[0],range[1]],
    change: function() { 
        range = $( ".slider" ).slider("option", "values");
        $("#low-price").text("Min: $"+range[0]);
        $("#high-price").text("Max: $"+range[1]);
    } 
});
```

The problem is that the step attribute does not function properly. With the above code I would think that each slide would change the value by 10, but it is stepping 1 value at a time. Any ideas on what is wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the option name, it should be [`step` not `steps`](http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/#option-step), like this:

```
$(".slider").slider({ 
    step: 10,          //step, singular
    animate: true,
    range: true, 
    min: 0, 
    max: 500, 
    values: [range[0],range[1]],
    change: function() { 
        range = $( ".slider" ).slider("option", "values");
        $("#low-price").text("Min: $"+range[0]);
        $("#high-price").text("Max: $"+range[1]);
    } 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the option should be step rather than steps.

Answer (score 0):

It should be:

```
step: 10
```

(a.k.a. not plural)